# Taking formatted input : sscanf not ignoring white spaces

Tags: c, scanf, formatted-input

I have to find out the input hours and minutes after taking inputs from the user of the form :

```
( Number1 : Number2 )
```

eg: ( 12 : 21 )

I should report 12 hours and 21 minutes and then again wait for input. If there is a mismatch in the given format, I should report it as invalid input. I wrote this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int hourInput=0,minutesInput=0; 
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t size;

    do
    {
        puts("\nEnter current time : ");
        getline ( &buffer, &size, stdin );

        if ( 2 == sscanf( buffer, "%d:%d", &hourInput, &minutesInput ) && hourInput >= 0 && hourInput <= 24 && minutesInput >=0 && minutesInput <= 60  )
        {

            printf("Time is : %d Hours %d Minutes", hourInput, minutesInput );
        }

        else
        {
            puts("\nInvalid Input");
        }   
    }

    while ( buffer!=NULL && buffer[0] != '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Q. if someone gives spaces between the number and `:`, my program considers it as invalid input, while I should treat it as valid.

Can someone explain why it is happening and any idea to get rid of this issue ? As far as I understand, sscanf should ignore all the white spaces ?

Comment: BTW: You accept "24" in hourInput, which is good for "24:00".  You also accept minutes "60".  Recommend "minutesInput < 60" instead of "minutesInput <= 60".

Comment: @chux Thanks to point that out. I had corrected it after posting here though.

Comment: Should you like to accept 24:00 (which for good: see ISO 8601), but not 24:01, you could use `... && hourInput >= 0 && minutesInput >=0 && minutesInput < 60 && ((hourInput*60 + minutesInput) <= 24*60)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow optional spaces before ':', replace

```
"%d:%d"
```

with

```
"%d :%d"
```

`sscanf()` ignores white space where its format directives tell it to ignore, not everywhere.  A whitespace character in the directive such as `' '` will ignore all white spaces.  `%d` as well as other integer and floating point directives will ignore leading white space.  Thus a space before `%d` is redundant.

C11 7,21,6,2,8 Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier.)

---

Additional considerations include using `%u` and `unsigned` as an alternate way to not accept negative numbers.  `strptime()` is a common function used for scanning strings for time info.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid comparing `sscanf()` return value. In your case, it is always depends on the user input. If user gives spaces between input this value changes.

Comment: Doesn't `sscanf()` depend upon char array and `scanf()` depend upon user input?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put a space before and after the colon, it will ignore any whitespace and still work when they don't put spaces before and after the colon.
Like this:

```
sscanf( buffer, "%d : %d", &hourInput, &minutesInput )
```

Answer (score 0):

use "%d : %d" as format string. it will work with and without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

1st thing allocate memory before using `buffer`

2nd is this a `C++` program or `C` as `getline` is not a `C standard` function.

Check this

```
int main()
{
        int x=0,y=0;
        char bff[]="7        8";
        sscanf(bff,"%d%d",&x,&y);
        printf("%d %d",x,y);
}
```

o/p-7 8

Comment: 1. Memory is allocated by getline. 2. It is tagged as C. 3. (12 foo,bar 32) will also work in that case, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

On [sscanf man pagez](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sscanf/)

**RETURN VALUE OF SSCANF** -

> These functions return the number of input items assigned.  This can
>   be
>        fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of a matching fail-
>        ure.  Zero indicates that, although there was input available, no conver-
>        sions were assigned; typically this is due to an invalid input character,
>        such as an alphabetic character for a `%d' conversion.  The value EOF is
>        returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion such as an end-
>        of-file occurs.  If an error or end-of-file occurs after conversion has
>        begun, the number of conversions which were successfully completed is
>        returned.

Now,

> if someone gives spaces between the number and :, my program considers
>   it as invalid input

Yes , it should consider it wrong because the `sscanf` reads the from the `buffer` in exactly the same way as `%d:%d`,but if a character in the input stream conflicts with format-string, the function ends, ending with a matching failure.

Characters outside of conversion specifications are expected to match the sequence of characters in the input stream; **the matched characters in the input stream are scanned but not stored.** (*Please see the emphasis on the sentence in bold*)

i.e, `sscanf` while writing to the memory ignores whitespaces.